# JQuery / HTML link does not load on first click

Tags: jquery, html, css

JQuery + HTML + CSS

I am trying to get the links on a nav bar to update a "div" tag that I have. I got that to work, but I have to click each hyperlink twice before it loads the page on the main viewer. Why? How do I make it load after only one click?

test.js:

```
function onScreen(id){
    $("a#" + id).click(function(){$("div#viewer").load(id + '.html')});  
}
```

main.html:

```
<a href="#" id="about" onclick="onScreen('about')">About Us</a>
<a href="#" id="account" onclick="onScreen('account')">My Account</a>
```

etc.

```
<div class ="article" id="viewer">
    <p>welcome to this awesome site! </div>
```

There is an "about.html" file (and all other necessary files) in the same folder. Again, the code functions, just not as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first click execute onScreen, which associate the load function to the click event.
The load function is thus triggered the second time you click.

**Edit**

A solution could be to remove the `onclick` attributes on your `<a href=#>` tags

```
$(function(){
    $("a[href='#']").click(function(){$("div#viewer").load(this.id + '.html')});
})
```

Comment: Yes - this explains the problem quite precisely.  What about a solution though? :)

Comment: True, I had only answered the first part of the question, edited

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. As to why, my first click loaded the second click function, is that right?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Actually, in your code, every click calls your `onScreen` function, which **adds** your loader function to the onClick event handlers. So when you click a third time your `onScreen` function is called once and your loader function **twice**! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Change onScreen to

```
function onScreen(id){
   $("div#viewer").load(id + '.html'); 
}
```

**Explanation:**

What you did before was attaching a click event to the link when *clicked*. That means when you clicked for the first time it enabled the link to load your content for the next click thus only working the second time.

Answer (score 2):

You simply have some redundant code there.  You attached two click events.

1. Inline in the markup with the `onClick` attribute.
2. In the `onScreen()` function with `.click()`.

Only after you click the link does the actual `.click()` handler get created.  So you had to click once to create a handler and then the second click would trigger the callback function.

You can remove the `.click()` and leave the code within that function.  So your `onScreen()` function would look like this -

```
function onScreen(id){
  $("div#viewer").load(id + '.html');
}
```

---

You could also improve on the code by using this syntax instead -

```
$('a.internalLink').on('click',function(
  $("div#viewer").load($(this).id + '.html');
));
```

This assumes that you give all your `<a>` tags that you want to behave like this a class attribute of `internalLink`.  Its much easier to give similar elements the same class name so that you can easily group them with a jQuery selector.

The newer [`.on()` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) are preferred since jQuery 1.7+

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll accept after I test it later today!

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... first off, this is not the nicest solution. a nicer solution would be:

```
<a href="about.html" class="scriptable" id="about">About Us</a>
<a href="account.html" class="scriptable" id="account">My Account</a>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     function displayScreen(screenname){
         var url_to_load = screenname + '.html';
         $('#viewer').load(url_to_load);

     }
     $('.scriptable').live("click", function(ev){
         var screenname = $(this).attr('id');
         displayScreen(screenname);
         ev.preventDefault();
     });
});
```

Facebook does a similar solution, albeit they do it with rel="ajaxify" attribute, but the principle is exactly the same.

(Next step: use some kind of history api to make URLs follow user navigation)

Comment: Any recomends on a particular history api?

Comment: https://github.com/balupton/History.js/ - sorry, there were some Olympic game ceremonies going on :)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you're using jQuery, ditch the inline `onclick` and bind instead. This makes your code cleaner, and easier to understand & modify.

```
<a href="#" id="about" class="viewer">About Us</a>
<a href="#" id="account" class="viewer">My Account</a>
<div class ="article" id="viewer">
    <p>welcome to this awesome site!</p>
</div>
​<script>
$(function(){
    $("a.viewer").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id') + '.html');
        $("div#viewer").load(this.id + '.html')
    });  
})​;
</script>
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/RuEPa/1/)

Comment: In your fiddle example you use jQuery 1.7 - why not move to the `.on()` function?

Comment: @Lix re: `on` you're right. re: semicolon, they're not required here. http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: Just because you *can* ommit them - doesn't mean you should.  I believe one should be consistent with their code styles.

Comment: I believe that I wrote the answer very quickly and since the missing `;` has no effect it is no big deal. Feel free to edit the answer and add it if it offends you so.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    $("div#viewer").load(this.id + '.html')
  });
});
```